# ANR on Mediarecorder onStop : Video Recording Camera API

Tags: android, debugging, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-debug

I have been trying to create a background video recoder using `Service` class and using `Camera API`. When I run the app, everything seems to be working fine. However, when I stop the Service, my app throws ANR. Using `DDMS tool`, I found following info about my `main` thread after I press stop recording button:

```
  at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)    
  at com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye.Services.VideoRecordingOldApiService.stopRecording(VideoRecordingOldApiService.java:212)  
  at com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye.Services.VideoRecordingOldApiService.onDestroy(VideoRecordingOldApiService.java:250)  
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:2877) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:162)    
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1466)   
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)   
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)    
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)   
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)    
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)   
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The `onDestroy()` method code of my `Service` class is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (linearLayout != null) {

            windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
            linearLayout = null;
        }
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera.lock();
            mCamera = null;

        }
    }
```

**EDITS: Rectified `Service` Class**

```
public class VideoRecordingOldApiService extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


    private Camera mCamera;
    private String outputFile;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private CameraCheck cameraCheck;
    private final static String TAG = "VideoRecorderService";
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler;


    public VideoRecordingOldApiService() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.surfaceview_layout, null);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textureView_width), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textureView_height)));
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                PixelFormat.OPAQUE
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        windowManager.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        cameraCheck = new CameraCheck();
        handler = new Handler();

        //Setup Notification
        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification;

        notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.videorecordicon)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.video_recorder_notification))
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_video_text) + "...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (initCamera()) {

            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Looper.prepare();

                    if (initRecorder()) {

                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.video_recorder_started, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't start MediaRecorder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    public String getFileName() {

        String fileName = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            fileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/" + "video_record" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

            Log.i("Camera Recorder", fileName);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No External Storage Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return fileName;
    }


    private boolean initCamera() {

        try {

            mCamera = cameraCheck.getDesiredCamera(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setRecordingHint(true);

            Camera.Size previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(),
                    surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight());
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.v(TAG, "Could not initialise the camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean initRecorder() {

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        outputFile = getFileName();


        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        profile.videoFrameWidth = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes().get(1).width;
        profile.videoFrameHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes().get(1).height;
        profile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
        profile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;


        try {
            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
            //mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());


            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder initialized successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder failed to initialize");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private void releaseCamera() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.lock();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            thread.interrupt();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.recording_done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (linearLayout != null) {

            windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
            linearLayout = null;
        }

        stopForeground(true);
        releaseCamera();
        thread = null;
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting ANR on `onStop()` method of Mediarecoder?? And what does DDMS tool indicate about `main` thread???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lifecycle callbacks of `Service` are always called on the main thread of your app.  A `Service` runs in the "background" only from a *user perception* standpoint.  If you want true background operations, you would need to use your own thread(s).  The call to `MediaRecorder.stop()` is a blocking call as it is talking to the media server process, telling it to stop operations.  This is taking too long (other main thread ops are blocked waiting) and the system declares ANR for your app and kills it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! I am using `SurfaceView` for video recording. Can you tell me where shall I call `Mediarecorder.onStop()`?? The recording is to be stopped by button press. @Larry Schiefer

Comment: You can have a separate thread running which does all of the media recorder interactions. Just send that thread a command to stop.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion in my code..now my app is not throwing ANR. It is successfully creating output file in the directory. However, when I play the output file, I get "Can't play this video" error. I have posted my complete `Service` class code. Can you please tell where things are going wrong??? @Larry Schiefer

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new SO question about that particular failure and provide logcat output (be sure it is for everything, not filtered for just your app.) That way people can see the new question and not have to sift through this entire thread.